# Is there a way to change UI for biometric authen in expo-local-authentication

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using `expo-local-authentication` and I need to modify the look and feel of the bio authen modal.

This is what I would like to modify

- Change the position of the modal (such as move it to the center of the screen)
- Change the labels, `Authenticate` or `Touch the fingerprint sensor`
- Change the color of the fingerprint

Not sure if this is possible in react-native?

[image]

Comment: no, I think its default